# Why was someone considered mentally unbalanced or crazy called a "crackpot"?

Tags: etymology, slang

I believe "crackpot" dates back to the last decade of the nineteenth century; however, I'm curious to know why "crackpot" was used to describe someone mentally unbalanced or crazy. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've always liked the euphemism "psychoceramic" for this.

Comment: http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/crackpot.html http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=crackpot   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank_%28person%29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OED's definition #5 for **cracked**...

> Of the brain, mind, etc.: Unsound, impaired, somewhat deranged.
>    Of a person: Unsound in mind, slightly insane, crazy.

...for which the first relevant citation is...

> **1610**   Bp. J. Hall Common Apol. against Brownists xxvii. 68
>    *That which this man was wont so oft to obiect to his brother (a crack't braine).*

As to the specific conjunction *crack**pot***, I think it's worth noting that ***-pot*** is appended to various other "fused words" applied (usually, *negatively*) to people - *moneypots, honeypot, fusspot, tosspot.*

I think it's fairly obvious that ***crack't/cracked*** in this context is just a slightly more figurative way of saying *broken, not functioning properly*. Per @Oldcat's comment below, additional  ***-pot*** component *could* be interpreted as *head, brain, skull*. Or it may be simply added for prosody (or by association with related forms), and not really add any specific extra meaning.

Comment: I think rather that 'pot' is a reference to the head. So a crack-pot would be a broken brained person.

Comment: @Oldcat: I'm not sure what you mean by "rather" there. I never actually suggested any *specific* meaning to the "suffix" ***-pot*** as in those examples (it's probably not consistent, anyway). Apparently, obsolete *pot of the head* was the *skull* (or *brainbox*, in which context it may be worth noting that *fusspot* also has the variant *fussbox*). OED's 1610 citation above explicitly says *crack't **braine***, but they have *"Would you not think him a little crack'd?"* from John Locke in 1693, so ***crack/cracked*** could stand alone in this sense since long ago (***pot*** may add nothing).

Comment: I am as an alternative suggesting a particular meaning to pot, meaning head.

Comment: @Oldcat: And it's a perfectly credible suggestion. All I'm saying is that until the last four words in my preceding sentence, I'd offered no other suggestion against which yours might be considered an "alternative". If it "means" anything at all, I'd say *pot = head, brain, skull* sounds perfectly reasonable. But taking particular note of [*fusspot, fussbox, fussbudget*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fussbox&searchmode=none) there may actually be little if any "meaning" to ***-pot*** here.

Comment: _Potty_ seems to show up at roughly the same time as crackpot.

Comment: @Frank: OED has ***crackpot*** from 1883, but at that time ***potty*** only had the sense of *petty, insignificant* (quite uncommon today, but lives on in *my* vocabulary as ***tinpot***). They don't record the *potty = crazy, mad* sense until 1920.

Comment: I was looking at the first quote from 1860/64 that says 'said of a rotten or unsound scheme' and took that to include 'a potty idea', maybe I was looking too hard.

Answer (score 2):

FumbleFingers has a great answer for the history of crackpot.  But know that I don't find this meaning to hold up with the younger generation.

If you call someone a crackhead, they are either an addict, or acting like a dumbass.  My kids are definitely crackheads sometimes.

If you call someone a crackpot you are basically calling them a crackhead.  Wrong or right the drug "crack" has changed the meaning to people.

Answer (score 1):

I think pot is being used in terms of "a collection of something" or another way to say "a lot of", so a moneypot is someone with a lot of money, a fusspot is a overly fussy person, a tosspot is someone who is very mucher a tosser (British slang) or very toss-y in nature.

A crackpot therefore, drawing on the suggested meaning for crack, would mean someone who is very crazy.

Comment: Good point - Fleshpot, fusspot, stinkpot and sexpot